# I am trying to construct an sqlalchemy engine using a dict which has variables parsed to it from tkinter

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlalchemy

Any help would be most appreciated. I have a connect engine using sqlalchemy, which connects perfectly. I would like to make it dynamic where a user provides the info in a tkinter Entry box and that information gets parsed into a dict which in turn gets called by a function and the engine is created from there.

My working engine is:

```
engine =    sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql+pg8000://myuser:mypass@localhost/mydb')
```

I would like something like this

```
sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql+pg8000://DBUSER:DBPASS@DBHOST/DBNAME')
```

where the variables are first supplied by tkinter Entry and placed into a dict, then read by the connection function.

I have the following

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import url

"""
These vars below are for testing. Ultimately they will be resolved
by a get() from tkinter which will take the values entered by a 
user into an Entry widget and place them into the dict below. 
The db_connect() func should build the url from the dict.
"""

DBNAME = 'mydb'
DBUSER = 'myuser'
DBPASS = 'password'
DBHOST ='localhost'
PNUM = '5432'
import json
import urllib.request as myurl

DATABASE = {
    'drivername': 'postgres+pg8000',
    'host': DBHOST,
    'port': PNUM,
    'username': DBUSER,
    'password': DBPASS,
    'database': DBNAME
}

def db_connect():
    create_engine(url(DATABASE))
"""This func should create the db engine connect


connect = sqlalchemy.create_engine(db_connect())

df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM nc_data",con=connect)
```

I get the error

db_connect
        return create_engine(url(DATABASE))
    TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Answer (score 6):

Feed it into sqlalchemy's `url.URL()` function by using keyword arguments

```
create_engine(url.URL(**DATABASE))
```

Notice the `**` and the correct method is `url.URL()`, not just `url` as per http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL

Reference on what `**` does: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: Thanks very much. This has put me on the right track. Much appreciated

Comment: @neilschumi:  you're welcome! If this answer wholly answers your question, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Solution I used was based on the make_url option: mystring = ('postgresql+pg8000://%s:%s@%s/%s') %     (DBUSER,DBPASS,DBHOST,DBNAME)

#Below URL to be built dynamically
    myurl = sqlalchemy.engine.url.make_url(mystring)

    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(myurl)

Comment: @neilschumi OK, but the single line answer I provided accomplishes exactly that... all you did was essentially reconstruct what the `url.URL` method already does for you.

Comment: Thanks Manuel. For some reason I was getting an error with the url.URL. method so you had put me on the right track and I used the make.url  method. Thanks again

Comment: @neilschumi glad you got it working. If there's nothing else with regards to this question, please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

One might consider a connection string.

```python
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

CONN_STR = "{0}://{1}:{2}@{3}:{4}/{5}".format(  # pylint: disable=C0209
    os.environ['DB_ENGINE'],
    os.environ['DB_USER'],
    os.environ['DB_PASS'],
    os.environ['DB_HOST'],
    os.environ['DB_PORT'],
    os.environ['DB_NAME']
)
ENGINE = create_engine(CONN_STR)
```