# Invalid attribute in connection string: DBCNAME. when using create_engine & Pandas to_sql

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

Afternoon,
Very new to python, but I'm stuck with the following error when trying to use `sqlalchemy` `create_engine` and `pandas` `to_sql` with Teradata.

> **Error message**    DatabaseError: (teradata.api.DatabaseError) (0, '[08001] [TPT][ODBC SQL Server Wire Protocol driver]Invalid Connection
>   Data., [TPT][ODBC SQL Server Wire Protocol driver]Invalid attribute in
>   connection string: DBCNAME.')

**Background**
I'm reading in some customer identifiers and connecting to a number of Teradata databases to extract some info and put it into pandas data frames,  as per sample in section one of the code below. This approach is repeated a number of times and works fine.  I now need to insert this data into another Teradata database. As such I would like to use sqlalchmey create_engine and pandas to_sql
I have installed "sqlalchemy-teradata" as well

The code throws the above error when the “df_name.to_sql… “ line is executed

I have read the following, but can’t seem to find how to pass  DBCNAME into the connection string, or what’s causing the error

[I am trying to construct an sqlalchemy engine using a dict which has variables parsed to it from tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852582/i-am-trying-to-construct-an-sqlalchemy-engine-using-a-dict-which-has-variables-p)
https://github.com/Teradata/sqlalchemy-teradata/wiki/Examples 
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html

I have Teradata SQL assistant installed which uses the following connection info, below,  which I can login to with no problems

```
[ODBC]  
DRIVER=Teradata  
UID= abcdef  
DBCNAME= aaaaa.bbb.ccccccc.co.uk
```

I can also ping the DBCname from  the command prompt , which works fine

Environment
3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] / windows 7 
Teradata version  15.10.05.04

```
# section one 
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
# define my sql string here 
xref_query = "SELECT A, B,C, "\
"FROM someting "\
"WHERE A= " +sql_param
#connect to terdata ** this works fine**
#Specify connection string
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER=
{Teradata};DBCName=aaaaa.bbb.ccccccc.co.uk;DATABASE=somthing;
Username=abcdef;password=ghijk')

#connect and run sql 
df_xref_temp = pd.read_sql(xref_query, conn)
conn.close()

#Section two
from sqlalchemy import create_engine 
#use sqlalchemy create_engine 
#abcdef  = teradata user name 
#ghijk = teradata password
#@aaaaa.bbb.ccccccc.co.uk = teradata DBCname
td_engine = create_engine(r'teradata://abcdef:ghijk@aaaaa.bbb.ccccccc.co.uk/databas_name')
print(td_engine)
#This results in 
"Engine(teradata://abcdef:ghijk:***@daaaaa.bbb.ccccccc.co.uk/database_name)"   
df_name.to_sql('fos_chtax_results',con=td_engine, if_exists='append', index 
=False)
```

Any help appreciated

Update 
Morning,

After a lot more reading I’ve manged to make some progress on this error

It seems that if I use a Hostname connection instead of a DNS connection and specify a default driver it works 
New code

```
td_engine = create_engine("teradata://abcdef:ghijk@aaaaa.bbb.ccccccc.co.uk/database_name?driver=Teradata")  
#new code using a variable 
td_engine = create_engine(con_str)
```

I can also replace the text string with a variable as to make it dynamic . However I would like to use a dictionary method , as described below , but I can’t find a way to include the extra data information for the Hostname approach i.e. “?driver=Teradata”. The documentation would seem to suggest its not supported ? 
[I am trying to construct an sqlalchemy engine using a dict which has variables parsed to it from tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852582/i-am-trying-to-construct-an-sqlalchemy-engine-using-a-dict-which-has-variables-p)

Comment: ** the line "#This results in..." is the result from printing td_engine

Comment: You can [edit] your post to include that information as opposed to putting it in a comment :)